# Vue test-utils mount is not initializing with propsdata

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have this component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-if="isAdmin">Admin Privileges</span>
    <span v-else>Not Authorized</span>
    <button>
      {{ msg }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SubmitButton",

  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  }
}
```

and this test script:

```
import SubmitButton from "@/components/SubmitButton.vue";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";

const msg = "submit";
const factory = (propsData) => {
  return shallowMount(SubmitButton, {
    propsData: {
      msg,
      ...propsData,
    },
  });
};

describe("does not have admin privileges", () => {
  it("renders a message", () => {
    const wrapper = factory();

    expect(wrapper.find("span").text()).toBe("Not Authorized");
    expect(wrapper.find("button").text()).toBe("submit");
  });
});

describe("has admin privileges", () => {
  it("renders a message", () => {
    const wrapper = factory({ isAdmin: true });

    expect(wrapper.find("span").text()).toBe("Admin Privileges");
    expect(wrapper.find("button").text()).toBe("submit");
  });
});
```

However the test is failing:
Expected: "submit"
Received: ""
Expected: "Admin Privileges"
Received: "Not Authorized"
My supposition is that it is not initializing the props, but in the tutorial it is working, so... Any idea why ? https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/components-with-props.html#refactor-with-a-factory-function

Comment: I just initialized a fresh project from Vue CLI, copied your component to the components folder, installed jest and @vue/test-utils, and created a test case with the code you provided. The 2 tests pass. How did you create your project?

Comment: I initialized it manually, maybe I did a mistake during creation, could u give me the steps you followed to create your project?

Comment: My Vue CLI version - Vue CLI v4.4.6
vue create project-test
cd project-test
vue add unit-jest
yarn add -D @vue/test-utils

Comment: Hi - glad you found my guide useful. I don't see any obvious problem here - it could be your configuration. You can grab working examples for this code for Vue 2 and 3 in the GH repo for the book: https://github.com/lmiller1990/vue-testing-handbook